# how to replace boolan value and rename the file

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to read a bunch of `.csv` files (100 or more) replace boolean value (true or false) with integer and save the file as `filename_conv.csv`.

i have below command to change boolean to int

```
sed -i 's/true/1/g' /file/path/*.csv
sed -i 's/false/0/g' /file/path/*.csv
```

and while saving the file, how do I rename the file as filename_conv.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the filenames ending in `.csv` and save the output of conversion with shell parameter expansion using redirection:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    sed 's/true/1/g;s/false/0/g' -- "$file" >"${file%%.*}_conv.csv"
done
```

The shell parameter expansion pattern `${file%%.*}` strips off the portion from last `.`, which is this case is `.csv`.

If you want to remove the original files too:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    sed 's/true/1/g;s/false/0/g' -- "$file" >"${file%%.*}_conv.csv" && rm -- "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `-i`option in place edit:

```
sed 's/true/1/g;s/false/0/g' "${filename}.csv" >"${filename}_conv.csv"
```

As suggested by @ViktorKhilin, adding `&& rm "${filename}.csv"` allows to remove input file if sed command succeeds.

Comment: ```sed 's/true/1/g;s/false/2/g' "${filename}.csv" >"${filename}_conv.csv" && rm -f "${filename}".csv``` You also can add this. If `sed` will finish its work successfully, filename `${filename}.csv` will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for response, when i execute above command, the result is getting saved as file name "_conv.csv" without any data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root        0 Feb 15 02:41 _conv.csv

Comment: the command is just given as example the variable filename must be assigned for example in a loop